# GREL: how to use OR in an if statement

Tags: if-statement, grel

How can I use 'OR' in GREL if statement?

I want to construct something like this

```
if(contains(value, "this") OR contains(value, "that"), True, False)
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

if(or(contains(value, "this"), contains(value, "that")), True, False)